# Boosting Elasticsearch documents based on the query provided

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a bit of an odd one, although not really for those of us who work in the eCommerce world I suppose.

I work for one of the largest children's retailers in the UK. We're currently knocking together a demonstration of our eCommerce platform with everything running off Elasticsearch rather than the 3rd party solution we currently use for our search. The 3rd party solution costs us thousands of £ every month, where as the architecture needed to run our entire site (search, range pages and product details pages) off ES actually costs a fraction of that.

I currently have most of the functionality working via ES just fine. However, our content co-ordinators really require the ability (via a CMS of our design) to boost certain VIP products, but based on the query provided. They know the document ID, and they know the query string they want to boost products for. I can write the CMS with a connector to get this information into ES but I'm unsure of what to do next.

Three options I have considered are as follows:

1. A separate ES index containing containing the document id (this is
   the product id), the query string to boost for and then the boost
   factor.
2. A property on the document itself that contains the query
   string to boost for and the boost factor.
3. Another index that has documents stored against a query to boost for, do this query first, and the normal query second as part of a multi-query and remove duplicates. This is my least favourite option... :(

These boost factors would then be applied using the function_score mechanism. Which one would you choose? Why? Is there an option I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get this working, kind of... I had to split my query into 2 queries. I created a new index, lets call it `boostvalues`. In `boostvalues` I had the following fields:

1. item_code (string, not analyzed)
2. query_string (string, analyzed with std analyzer)
3. boost_factor (integer, not analyzed)

Then for every search query that comes in I do a search against the `boostvalues` index first. I then use any returned results to dynamically populate the function_score arguments like so:

```
    if(isset($boostResults) && is_array($boostResults) && (int)$boostResults['hits']['total']>0) {
        foreach($boostResults['hits']['hits'] as $boostValue) {
            $searchParams['body']['query']['function_score']['functions'][] = array(
                "filter" => array("term" => array("id" => $boostValue['_source']['id'])),
                "script_score" => array("script" => $boostValue['_source']['boostFactor'])
            );
        }
    }
```

I'm using the official Elasticsearch PHP library by the way. This gives the desired effect. The beaty of this mechanism that I didn't realise until I tried it is that when getting the boost values I can also use function scoring on that to modify the boost factor based on how close the query is to the stored query string.